# How can run Docker in linux 20.04 in Windows 11

Tags: windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

[image]

Hi, I have this problem, trying to running Docker in Ubuntu 20.04 in windows 11 using the WSL, I installed it using the official documentation in https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/,  I tried with some commands like:

- sudo service docker start | restart

Show me OK but this didn't work when I tried to execute again the run hello-world command.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install Docker **for Windows** and manage it from there, rather than a service within WSL. Then in the preferences, you can [link it to WSL2](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/#enabling-docker-support-in-wsl-2-distros), where it'll install the Docker CLI.